# "Перевести во множественное число" или "Поставить во множественное число"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Перевести во множественное число" или "Поставить во множественное число"?

Comment: контекст???

Comment: Здесь правильно написано? "Какие слова можно переводить во  множественное число мужского рода?" Или нужно заменить слово "переводить " на слово"ставить",как грамотнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, ответ должен быть такой: "Поставить во множественное число" или "Образовать форму множественного числа от..."

Comment: Конечно?
Первое, что нашлось: 
  
Максим Кронгауз говорит: «Да, это видно даже в форме первого лица — царское "мы" вместо "я", то есть тоже перевод во множественное число. Так что, здесь язык иногда использует те возможности, которые открывает перед ним грамматическая система. Вот такое как бы повышение статуса — [b][i]перевод во множественное число[/i][/b]».
(курсив мой - b-s)
http://www.svoboda.org/content/article/133613.html

виктор1799, совет: не ведитесь на фейковые вопросы. Если слишком простой вопрос задан, то или есть реальные сомнения или это скрытый подвох. Не обижайтесь.

Answer (score 1):

> Здесь правильно написано? "Какие слова можно переводить во множественное число мужского рода?"

Грамматически - правильно. По сути - ерунда. Можно перевести во множественное число. 
И тут "перевести" вполне уместно, "ставить" хуже. Хотя правильнее всего будет "От каких слов можно образовать множественное число" - здесь Виктор абсолютно прав.

Но при чем тут "мужской род"?

> Или нужно заменить слово "переводить " на слово"ставить",как грамотнее?

Грамотнее - поинтересоваться у автора, что он имел в виду под "множественным числом мужского рода". Контекст нужен, возможно там имеется в виду совсем не грамматический род, а, скажем, название самца животного - тут недавно была перекликающаяся тема про кошек.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!!!некоторые слова в арабском языке переводятся в форму так называемого" правильного" ("целого") множественного числа, а некоторые в форму так называемого "ломанного"...

Comment: Так это не про русский???
Тогда пардон, там и терминология может (даже - должна) быть своя, переводить надо с большой осторожностью.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и *привести* (пример со словом) *во множественном числе*.